# Image Magick - how to create a pdf document from an image and not make it look like an image - PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I am trying to generate pdf documents from image files and I am using image magick with PHP.  Below is a result of this (my generated pdf on the right) and that generated by adobe scan (pdf on the left).  how do I get my pdf to look like that on the left - this 'flat'/contrast kind of effect where the shadow etc from my pdf is not present?  Please see image below.

[image]

image magick PHP:

```
$im = new imagick($sourcePathOfImage);

// Get dimension of source image
$geo = $im->getImageGeometry();
$srcImgWidth = $geo['width'];
$srcImgHeight = $geo['height'];
$srcWHRatio = $srcImgWidth/$srcImgHeight;

// RESIZE IMAGE
$resizedW = $desiredWidth;
$resizedH = $desiredWidth/$srcWHRatio;
$im -> resizeImage($resizedW, $resizedH, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

// SET TO PDF
$image -> setImageFormat('pdf');
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing it, but the Imagick equivalent of -negate -lat -negate does what you want. But I cannot find the equivalent of -lat in Imagick at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php. Also you can use my script, textcleaner, from PHP exec() to do what you want. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: @fmw42 haven't you quoted  the same link twice? I would be interested in looking at your textcleaner.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, I accidentally put the same link at the end. I have no other link. You are welcome to try my textcleaner script. I believe the equivalent of -lat is http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.adaptivethresholdimage.php in Imagick